# send several messages to WebSocket Clients in an Azure Serverless Function

Tags: azure, websocket

I have the use case to send more then one message to connected WebSockets from an Azure Serverless function.

Let's pretent, a client sends me (via WebSocket) the number 5. Then I receive this message on the Sever(less) side in Azure and want to send 5 messages to the connected WebSocket.

All I currently have is the tutorial function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/quickstart-serverless?tabs=javascript

```js
module.exports = async function (context, data) {
    context.bindings.actions = {
        "actionName": "sendToAll",
        "data": `[${context.bindingData.request.connectionContext.userId}] ${data}`,
        "dataType": context.bindingData.dataType
    };
    // UserEventResponse directly return to caller
    var response = { 
        "data": '[SYSTEM] ack.',
        "dataType" : "text"
    };
    return response;
};
```

This serverless function is triggered when a new message from a client arrives and clearly only sends back one msssage by returning that message as function result.

How can I achieve now to send more messages to the connected WebSockets and not doing this via return type but somehow else (e.g. to wait a certain time in between sending a message to a client)?

Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I have created a Azure webpubsub service.

[image]

I have created a function app called **webpubsubTrigger** by using CLI and tested works fine. I followed this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/quickstart-serverless?tabs=javascript#create-the-functions)

[image]
Instead of returning a single response. `WebPubSubAsyncCollector` allows you to send multiple messages to one or more WebSocket clients.
Try this below whether it works.

```
module.exports = async function (context, data) {
    const num = parseInt(data);
    const output = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        output.push({
            "action": "sendToAll",
            "payload": `Message ${i + 1}`
        });

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }

    context.bindings.webPubSub = new WebPubSubAsyncCollector(output);

    return {
        "data": `Sent ${num} messages.`,
        "dataType": "text"
    };
};
```

For much more reference check below.

- [Azure Functions JavaScript developer guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2)
- [Azure Web PubSub Service JavaScript SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/javascript-sdk)
- [WebPubSubServiceClient class reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/web-pubsub/webpubsubserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest)
- [Build WebSocket-based web apps with the Azure Web PubSub Service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Oa-PApgNnw)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. On a first sight, this function seems to send the data to the WebSocket clients when the function itself is quite, isn't it, because `output .push` is just appending something to a list (so nothing special happening here). Then that output is used within the collector and then the function is returned. I don't really see how a message is sent, then 1 second wait, then another message, followed by another wait... Or do I just miss something?